# Build bitcoin-qt on OSX

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I recently cloned from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.  I followed the documentation in  `doc/build-osx.md`.  I can build and run `bitcoind` without a problem.  But I would have expected to see `bitcoin-qt` built, but I do not see it anywhere.  Am I doing something wrong?  What is the build target for `bitcoin-qt` or, more generally, how do I build it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply an extra option to compile a QT binary.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-qt
make -j8
```

Your binary will then be in `/src/qt/` as expected. To turn it into an `.app` you'll need to read `contrib/macdeploy/readme.md` and then run `make deploy` to wrap it in an application bundle ready for release.